# oc exec with heredoc: cannot pass variable into command to execute in container; rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error

Tags: bash, openshift, herestring

I want to use `oc exec` to execute a `cat` in my pod. In this `cat` command I need to expand some variable.

```
cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running
```

So, I try this:

```
oc exec -i $pod -- '"/bin/bash" -s <<EOF cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running EOF'
```

But I cannot get it working.

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec: \"\\\"/bin/bash\\\" -s <<-EOF cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running EOF\": stat \"/bin/bash\" -s <<-EOF cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running EOF: no such file or directory"
```

I can put cat and bash in separate lines, but the error is the same: `$index` not expanded.

```sh
                    oc exec -i $pod -- '"/bin/bash" -c <<EOF
                    cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running
                    EOF'
```

Error:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec: \"\\\"/bin/bash\\\" -c <<EOF\\n                    cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running\\n                    EOF\": stat \"/bin/bash\" -c <<EOF\n                    cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running\n                    EOF: no such file or directory"
```

Comment: `<<EOF cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running EOF` does not workis not a valid HERE document. You have to put the `cat ...` part into a separate line, and the terminating `EOF` must also be in a line of its own.

Comment: Hi @user1934428 I break the lines but still error. `$index` is not expanded, equals to empty str.

Comment: You have a single quote after the `EOF`.

Comment: Because the first quote is single quote, after `--`.

Comment: This means that you have no newline after the last line of the HERE document. I don't know how forgiving bash is, but technically speaking, this is not correct. BTW, is there a reason why you use a HERE-doc for just submitting a  single `cat`?

Comment: BTW, you did not show how you define `index`, but `$index` won't be expanded by the invoking shell due to your single quotes.  Perhaps it will be expanded if you put it into the environment (to answer this, I would need to know more about _openshift_).

Comment: Yeah. Maybe u r right, no need to heredoc for cat. I found a solution to it, using rsh but not exec. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way without using heredoc.

`oc rsh` can run commands and return results directly:

```
oc rsh pod_name cat /opt/data/...
```

So that's what I need. Then I don't need `oc exec`.

And, see the error message, it says:

```sh
stat \"/bin/bash\" -s <<-EOF cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running EOF: no such file or directory
```

Notice the `stat`, it seems to be looking for a file.

Comment: _it seems to be looking for a file_ :  Because in your original attempt, you had the construct  `os exec .... 'long string between quotes'`, and the whole string was there fore taken as command to be executed. The general syntax is `os exec COMMAND ARG1 ...`, and you provided, syntactically, only COMMAND and no arguments. See [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/executing_remote_commands.html).

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Good doc. So what if a command does not need args?

Comment: Then you don't provide any :-))))

Answer (score 0):

you can try to quote EOF:

```
oc exec -i $pod -- /bin/bash -s <<'EOF' 
cat /opt/amq/data/split-$index/running
EOF
```

see https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/